# Restrict Rails Translated routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, internationalization

I have a large website setup with many different locales with translations for different locales.

ie.

```
http://<server>.com/test/123
http://<server>.es/prueba/123
http://<server>.pt/teste/123
```

Where the first parameter is a I18n translation of the same keyword. This is all in place and works fine

routes.rb

```
localized(I18n.available_locales) do
  constraints(TestMatcher.new) do
    get '/test/:product/:type/:id'
  end
end
```

And in my `config/locales/<language>/<language>/routes.yml`

ie de.yml

```
de:
  named_routes_path:
    'test(/:product)': 'test(/:product)'
```

The problem is I want to only allow the one language per domain:

For example if I am on the Portuguese site and I to to 
`http://<server>.pt/test/123` I want to be redirected to `http://<server>.es/prueba/123`

and when I am on the english site (.co.uk, .com ...)and I visit `http://<server>.com/prueba/123` I want to be redirected to `http://<server>.com/test/123`

Using rails 3.2.18 and ruby 2.1.1

Thanks